# Listen for object changes from the outside in C#

Tags: c#

I have an object which I would like to monitor in case its data changes. However I am not allowed to add additional events or interfaces like INotifyPropertyChanged to the object, so I need to purely watch it from the outside and see if it has changed in character and the go through all it's properties to identify what has changed.

So I basically need a FileSystemWatcher, but for an object.

Does C# offer any functionality I am looking for here?

Comment: Well if you can't use `INotifyPropertyChanged` you're going to have to cache all of the properties' values and check then with the current values periodically.

Comment: Is the object serializable?  One very inefficient (but simple) way to handle this would be to periodically serialize the object to memory and compare that to it's previous serialization.  Depending on how large the objects are and how often it needs to poll for changes this could be VERY bad for performance though.

Comment: The object are small enough for this kind of operation and it's only code on my companies private test software, so quality and performance is not a priority. It just needs to work. 

It looks like though that I have to poll the data myself in intervals though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll have to brute-force it and do something like capturing the state of the object and then look for differences when you need to detect changes (either through periodic polling or at specific points where you need to know the diffs).

This, I believe, is what a number of systems that monitor for changes in data model objects do (e.g. RavenDB).

I made a quick and dirty console app that roughly does what you are wanting. It should be enough to give you an idea but will need a whole lotta work if you want to use it in production code. :)

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        DemoClass demo = new DemoClass { IntValue = 1, StringValue = "asdf" };

        var watcher = new DemoClassWatcher();
        watcher.Capture(demo);

        demo.StringValue = "1234";
        var results = watcher.Compare(demo); // results = "StringValue"
        demo.IntValue = 1234;
        results = watcher.Compare(demo); // results = "StringValue", "IntValue"
        watcher.Capture(demo);
        results = watcher.Compare(demo); // results = empty
    }
}

public class DemoClass
{
    public string StringValue { get; set; }
    public int IntValue { get; set; }
}

public class DemoClassWatcher
{
    private DemoClass lastRecorded = null;

    public void Capture(DemoClass objectToWatch)
    {
        lastRecorded = new DemoClass()
        {
            IntValue = objectToWatch.IntValue,
            StringValue = objectToWatch.StringValue
        };
    }

    public List<string> Compare(DemoClass currentObject)
    {
        var changes = new List<string>();
        var props = typeof(DemoClass).GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance);
        foreach (var propertyInfo in props)
        {
            var currentVal = propertyInfo.GetValue(currentObject);
            var prevVal = propertyInfo.GetValue(lastRecorded);
            if (currentVal is IComparable)
            {
                if ((currentVal as IComparable).CompareTo(prevVal) != 0)
                    changes.Add(propertyInfo.Name);
                continue;
            }

            throw new NotSupportedException("Properties must support IComparable until someone fixes me up");
        }
        return changes;
    } 
}
```

Comment: Interesting idea Rob. I'll look into this and see this could work well with my problem at hand.

Comment: I'm marking this as an answer because of the way it works with Type and GetProperties method. It really easy to implement.

Answer (score 0):

You can't listen for events that are not there, but you can poll the states and compare them to their previous state.

Pseudocode:

```
///initial config: 
yourObject = getAReferenceToTheObject();
previousState = new ObjectClass(yourObject);

///somewhere in a thread/loop
if (previousState.SomeProperty!= yourObject.SomeProperty){
    //state changed for SomeProperty on yourObject
}
//TODO: check other properties
previousState = new ObjectClass(yourObject); //implement copy constructor
```